# patch.diff file not working with CSS file

Tags: eclipse, svn, patch

I am using eclipse svn to maintain version for developing java web application with spring and hibernate.
Now i am creating patch now try to applying that patch. My patch is working well with .java and .jsp files but it is not working with .css file.
I have seen that patch successfully created file for .css but it is not applying.
Please help me to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer your question. What command are you using to patch the CSS file? Do you get an error, and if so, what is the exact error text? What do the patch and source files look like? Can you create a short, reproducible test case that duplicates the issue?

Comment: I am using eclipse UI to create and apply the patch. when i try to apply above patch then there is no error message, but that not affect to the file also. means patch apply successfully but cannot see any changes.